# Authenicate Webservice for push notifications

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, ssl, push-notification, mpns

I am working on WP7 app that require Push notifications. As per Microsoft requirement, Web-service should be authenticated over TLS. How to setup certificate on my shared hosting so that my webservice will be authenticated for push service.

Answer (score 0):

This document might help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941099%28v=vs.92%29.aspx. Also, I wanted to clarify that it is not mandatory as you are suggesting above.  Paraphrasing: Microsoft **recommends** that one should send notifications over HTTPS instead of HTTP. Also, this would ok if the service can do with 500 push notifications per subscription per day. Ref:

> We recommend setting up an authenticated web service to send your
>   notifications to the Microsoft Push Notification Service, because
>   communication occurs over an HTTPS interface for better security.
>   Authenticated web services do not have a daily limit on the number of
>   push notifications they can send. Unauthenticated web services, on the
>   other hand, are throttled at a rate of 500 push notifications per
>   subscription per day.

Hopefully this helps you out.